# Open file without downloading it and getting A resource failed to call close

Tags: view, download, huawei-mobile-services

Trying to open file without downloading it, but on huawei with android 11 files don't opening, showing loading and white screen. On Sumsung with android 11 works fine.
Huawei in log has `W/System: A resource failed to call close` 
but download works fine on Huawei.

Any solution?

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(href);

String detectedMime = getMimeType(fileUri.toString().toLowerCase());
String mime = getMimeType(fileUri.toString().toLowerCase());

intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, mime);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Maybe some permissions required?

Any library for file viewing?

Answer (score 0):

Check Mime Type has set correctly. Consider calling MimeTypeMap#getMimeTypeFromExtension() to get MimeType.

What type of file are you trying to open without downloading? Please provide more file details and code you are using.